# Type guard on readonly value

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm trying to add a type guard to distinguish between success and failure calls to an API, where the response shares the same top level format:

```
//success
{
  statusCode: 200,
  result: { foo: 'hello' }
}

//failure
{
  statusCode: 300,
  result: { errorMessage: 'you broke me' }
}
```

```
interface APISuccessResult<T> {
  readonly statusCode: number;
  result: T;
}

interface APIFailedResult<T> {
  readonly statusCode: number;
  result: T;
}

type APIResult<T, E> = APISuccessResult<T> | APIFailedResult<E>;

const isAPISuccessResult = <T, E>(result: APIResult<T, E>): result is APISuccessResult<T> => {
  return result.statusCode < 300;
};

const isAPIFailedResult = <T, E>(result: APIResult<T, E>): result is APIFailedResult<T> => {
  return result.statusCode >= 300;
};

type FooSuccess = {
  foo: string;
}

type FooFailure = {
  errorMessage: string;
}

const x: APIResult<FooSuccess, FooFailure> = {} as any as APIResult<FooSuccess, FooFailure>;

if (isAPISuccessResult(x)) {
  console.log(x.result.foo); 
    // Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'FooSuccess | FooFailure'
}
```

I would expect this to work, but it doesn't...

Is it possible to add a type guard on a value of a property?  I could see issues with this if the value could change, but if it's readonly it seems like it should be ok.

### Update

Looks like maybe I just had my type guard function wrong.  Here's a [playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-tq52n) with it working as expected.

Comment: `any | APISuccessResult<T>` this type collapses to `any`.

Comment: Just add the type to `isAPISuccessResult(x)`.  It should look like `isAPISuccessResult<FooSuccess>(x)`

Comment: @zerkms ugh yea fixing that type solves the issue

Comment: Your problem is `APISuccessResult<T>` and `APIFailureResult<T>` are identical types and there's no way for the compiler to distinguish them.  TypeScript's type system is [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), not nominal, so the fact that the names `APISuccessResult` and `APIFailureResult` differ doesn't affect anything.

Comment: @jcalz it actually works if I get the type guard param type right

Comment: What do you mean by "right"?  It is true that sometimes the compiler will act is if it distinguishes some types nominally, but it's not good practice to rely on it (because it often breaks).  To be safe I'd try to add a distinguishing property to those types. But if you're happy with the current definitions then I'll stop pestering you about it.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz not sure what you mean... the compiler is giving me the correct type when I distinguish it with the type guard function, which is all I wanted.  I updated my question with a ts-playground link where it "works"